# argparse excludes short identifiers when long ones are present

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to add a character and a keyword to the same parameter which means I may refer to by value or by keyword, ex: `python my_module.py -k abc` or `python --keyword abc` and I'm expecting both to work however when I add a name and I call `args.k` I get a Namespace error. I looked up here and I found questions that are asking about the same error but none is answering my question.

```
def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--website',
                        help='Website that returns ip address as response content',
                        default='http://icanhazip.com')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                        help='File containing raw proxies delimited by \n',
                        default='proxy_urls.txt')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timeout', help='Request timeout', default=10, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--socks', help='4 or 5 for SOCKS version', default='')
    parser.add_argument('-j', '--jobs', help='Number of parallel jobs', default=4, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output destination', default='.')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    tester = ProxyTester(args.f, args.w, args.t, args.s)
    tester.test_proxies(args.j, args.o)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

In:

```
>> python3 proxy_tester.py
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxy_tester.py", line 152, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "proxy_tester.py", line 147, in main
    tester = ProxyTester(args.f, args.w, args.t, args.s)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Here is the output of `print(args)`:

```
Namespace(file='proxy_urls.txt', jobs=4, output='.', socks='', timeout=10, website='http://icanhazip.com')
```

Comment: argparse uses the long option names: `file` instead of `f`, `timeout` instead of `t`, etc.

Comment: And what is the point of including 2 options as long as it will only include the long ones? I mean what is the point of specifying `-c` as long as I already defined `--char`?

Comment: You can use both forms of the option in your CLI. But the Python structure which contains the data make the data accessable only by the long form.

Comment: @VPfB sure, I understand why I get the error, I want to do the same thing(that it recognizes both long and short) without getting the error, it does not make sense to me if it will only be able to recognize the long ones, then there is no point of defining 2 arguments.

Comment: @Tryph I want to either figure out why the people who wrote this `argparse`  were thinking when they provided a useless additional argument or what I don't know yet that can make me include both and still them being recognized by the interpreter

Comment: @sK500 I do not understand what you dislike. The user can use `-f xyz` or `--file xyz`  and the program always gets the value in `args.file`

Comment: It is typical POSIX convention to allow options to be specified using a single dash and letter, or a double dash and a verbose name. Both options are equal, they specify the same parameter, simply once tersely and once verbosely. Within your code, you do not want to have to consider both options, you want that standardised to one possible option. Argparse uses the verbose name for the parsed parameter.

Comment: Just to add to all that been said, you can always override the argument's attribute name in the parsed args with the [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) parameter

Comment: @VPfB There's some kind of misunderstanding on my part, I thought they can neither be called through `args.c` instead of `args.char` as well as they are completely wiped even if I passed the value through the single character and called `args.char` an error would occur(that's what I thought) this was the part I was upset about and this is because the single character identifiers were not present in the namespace so I thought they are gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is POSIX convention to allow arguments to be passed either as terse single dash and single letter, or verbosely as double dash and verbose name. Especially with boolean flags this makes commands much quicker and shorter:

```
curl -LIv
curl -L -I -v
curl --location --head --verbose
```

These commands are all exactly equivalent, but the first is a lot quicker to type once you have remembered the shorthand.

Within your Python code, you obviously want that standardised to one parameter. You *don't* want to have to do:

```
if args.L or args.location: ...
```

Argparse uses the verbose name as the canonical name for the argument. You can customise that using [the `dest` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest).

Comment: Does this imply that if I did something like `python -s abc` and called the argument by the long name `args.something`, it will still have `'abc'` as the value? I'm asking because the single character args were not present in the namespace so I implied they do not exist or are being cancelled by the long ones

Comment: Yes, exactly. For `.add_argument('-s', '--something')`, the argument will *always* be `args.something`, regardless of how you supply it on the command line. That's abstracted away so you don't need to care about how exactly the argument was passed and your code doesn't need to be tightly bound to the CLI interface.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, I asked the question in the first place because when I noticed the absence of the single character args in the namespace I implied they are being cancelled or overriden somehow